# RxJS chained requests in switchMap, handle errors in inner request

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have 2 dependant API calls: getCars needs the user id from getUser.

It may happen that a user will not have cars, so the API will throw 404.

How can I return the aggregated response, and when no cars are returned, just use null/undefined for userData.cars ?

I tried using a catchError in the pipe of getCars, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
getUser().pipe(
      switchMap(user => user.creditScore > 70 ? 
        getCars(user.id).pipe(
          catchError(() => of(undefined)),
          map( cars => ({user, cars}) )
        )
       : of({user: user, cars: undefined)
      )
    ).subscribe((userData) => {
      if (userData.user) {
        ........
      }
      if (!!userData.cars) {
        .........
      }
    },
    err => {
      ......
    });
```

Comment: It can depend on what getCars look like. Can you add that to your Q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure all your code paths return or throw something in your catchError.
Also, use rxjs `of` operator to return your default value as an observable.
This code should be correct:

```js
getUser().pipe(
  switchMap(user => getCars(user.id).pipe(
    catchError((error) => {
      if (error.status == 404) return of([]);
      else throw error;
    }),
    map(cars => ({user, cars}))
  ))
).subscribe(res => ..., err => ...);
```

In case of an user with cars, `res` equals to:

```js
{
  user: { id: 1 },
  cars: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2} ]
}
```

In case of an user without any car (because of a `404` on your `getCars`), `res` equals to:

```js
{
  user: { id: 1 },
  cars: []
}
```

In case of an unexpected error in your `getCars` (such as a 401), the error is normally raised and you can get it in `err` inside your subscribe.